# Integrate Alfresco with an existing website

Tags: alfresco

I have developed some web pages with html,jsp, java deployed with apache Tomcat server.It's an educational website.I would like to add some functionality to it such as user updation of content, publishing using Alfresco. Can anyone tell me how to integrate Alfresco into that website? It is my project... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use Alfresco WCM or the latest Alfresco 3.4 WebQuickStart. You won't need to write any custom code, just need to define your website in the WCMQS template.

With this, you can have in context editing and can have direct access to Alfresco. It's a full-blown WCM/CMS package, but you can just use whatever you want from it.

Look at this intro video on youtube: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vfQrRzt4HIw

Answer (score 0):

From your JSP/Java, you can call the Alfresco REST API:

http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Repository_RESTful_API_Reference

The REST API is easy to use, and it can do whatever you might want to do with Alfresco: read content, write content, search, ...